# upload video to youtube using php

Tags: php, youtube

I am beginner in php. I want to upload video on youtube using php. but `HTTP ERROR 404` occurs while running this demo . here is the demo link that i used .

http://www.codexworld.com/upload-video-to-youtube-using-php/

and I created `oauthClientID` and `oauthClientSecret` from google accounts. and put it under config file.

```
<?php

    // OAUTH Configuration
    $oauthClientID = 'xxxxx';
    $oauthClientSecret = 'xxxxxxx';
    $baseUri = 'http://example.com/upload-video-to-youtube-using-php/';
    $redirectUri = 'http://example.com/upload-video-to-youtube-using-php/youtube_upload.php';

    define('OAUTH_CLIENT_ID',$oauthClientID);
    define('OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET',$oauthClientSecret);
    define('REDIRECT_URI',$redirectUri);
    define('BASE_URI',$baseUri);

    // Include google client libraries
    require_once 'src/Google/autoload.php'; 
    require_once 'src/Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'src/Google/Service/YouTube.php';
    session_start();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(OAUTH_CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
    $client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI);

    // Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

?>
```

and here is my redirect url code

```
<?php
//echo "www";exit;
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'includes/DB.php';
// create an object of class DB.
$db = new DB;

if(isset($_REQUEST['videoSubmit'])){
    $videoTitle = $_REQUEST['title'];
    $videoDesc = $_REQUEST['description'];
    $videoTags = $_REQUEST['tags'];

    if($_FILES["videoFile"]["name"] != ''){
        $fileSize = $_FILES['videoFile']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['videoFile']['type'];
        $fileName = str_shuffle('nityanandamaity').'-'.basename($_FILES["videoFile"]["name"]);
        $targetDir = "videos/";
        $targetFile = $targetDir . $fileName;
        $allowedTypeArr = array("video/mp4", "video/avi", "video/mpeg", "video/mpg", "video/mov", "video/wmv", "video/rm");
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowedTypeArr)) {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['videoFile']['tmp_name'], $targetFile)) {
                $videoFilePath = $targetFile;
            }else{
                header('Location:'.BASE_URI.'index.php?err=ue');
                exit;
            }
        }else{
            header('Location:'.BASE_URI.'index.php?err=fe');
            exit;
        }

        // insert video data
        $db->insert($videoTitle,$videoDesc,$videoTags,$videoFilePath);

    }else{
        header('Location:'.BASE_URI.'index.php?err=bf');
        exit;
    }
}

// get last video data
$result = $db->getLastRow();



/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google Developers Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */



if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
      die('The session state did not match.');
    }

    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    header('Location: ' . REDIRECT_URI);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

$htmlBody = '';
// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try{
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = $result['video_path'];

    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle($result['video_title']);
    $snippet->setDescription($result['video_description']);
    $snippet->setTags(explode(",",$result['video_tags']));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));

    // Read the media file and upload it.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }
    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);

    // Update youtube video ID to database
    $db->update($result['video_id'],$status['id']);
    // delete video file from local folder
    @unlink($result['video_path']);

    $htmlBody .= "<p class='succ-msg'>Video have been uploaded successfully.</p><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= '<embed width="400" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$status['id'].'"></embed>';
    $htmlBody .= '<li><b>Title: </b>'.$status['snippet']['title'].'</li>';
    $htmlBody .= '<li><b>Description: </b>'.$status['snippet']['description'].'</li>';
    $htmlBody .= '<li><b>Tags: </b>'.implode(",",$status['snippet']['tags']).'</li>';
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    $htmlBody .= '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';

  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>', htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    $htmlBody .= 'Please reset session <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
    // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $htmlBody = <<<END
    <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
    <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload video to YouTube using PHP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="youtube-box">
        <h1>Upload video to YouTube using PHP</h1>
        <div class="video-up">
            <a href="<?php echo BASE_URI; ?>">New Upload</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <?php echo $htmlBody; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have one more closing </div> tag in the html part

Comment: ohh yes,,, i remove that. can you please give the solution for my question